# how can I read and unpack a protobuf c packed message in server side(using sockets)

Tags: sockets, protobuf-c

I,m totally new in  protobuf-c
I,m trying to create a socket connection and send protobuf packed message over the socket using c language
I packed the message within client code and send it to the server.But the server failed to receive the packed data and unpack it
my client code is

**client.c**

```
void *clientThread(void *arg)
{
Messages t_message = MESSAGES__INIT;
//while(1)
{
    void *buf;
    unsigned len;
    int32_t s32_send_status;

    t_message.name="anu";

    len=messages__get_packed_size(&t_message);
    buf=malloc(len);
    messages__pack(&t_message,buf);

    s32_send_status=send(gs32_clientSocket ,buf,len,0);

    //s32_send_status=send(gs32_clientSocket ,(unsigned char *)
            //(&t_message),sizeof(t_message) ,0);

    if(s32_send_status>0){
        printf("data send to server.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("failed to send data to server\n");
```

And my server code is

**server.c**

```
void *socketThread(void *arg)
{

Messages *t_message;
uint8_t buf[1024];
int32_t len;
// unsigned length;
//while(1)
{
    gs32_valread = read( gs32_new_socket,buf,len);

    if(gs32_valread==0){
         printf("disconnected\n");
         exit(1);
    }
    else if(gs32_valread<0){
         printf("error\n");
         exit(1);
    }
        else{

        t_message = messages__unpack(NULL,len,buf);

        printf("name=%s\n",t_message->name);

        messages__free_unpacked(t_message,NULL);
    }
    sleep(1);
    close(gs32_new_socket);
}
return NULL;
}
```

if my packing is correct how can I unpack it in the server side.
If anybody know this answer please help me to solve it.Thank you

Comment: It looks like you declare `int32_t len;` but you never give it a value. When you go to read the socket into the buffer `gs32_valread = read( gs32_new_socket,buf,len);` it's reading 0 bytes?